# Pandas Dataframe with two columns whose values need to alternate as values

Tags: pandas, group-by, pivot

I have a pandas dataframe in the form:

| name | class | #absence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | class1 | 1 |
| name1 | class2 | 5 |
| name1 | class3 | 3 |
| name2 | class1 | 6 |
| name2 | class2 | 4 |
| name2 | class3 | 7 |

I want to get it in the form:

| name | class1 | #absence | class2 | #absence | class3 | #absence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | class1 | 1 | class2 | 5 | class3 | 3 |
| name2 | class1 | 6 | class2 | 4 | class3 | 7 |

I have tried various combinations of groupby, pivot, stack etc.. but can't quite seem to get exactly what I need.

Thank you!

Comment: check #10 in the duplicate

Comment: @mozway, he will not manage to pull in columns of #absence just by pivoting

Comment: @NoobVB there is a bit of extra work for the exact output, but the core logic to pivot class and #absence is well described in the duplicate

Answer (score -1):

You can use a core [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then rework the dataframe by selectively flattening the MultiIndex:

```
(df.assign(col=df.groupby('name').cumcount()+1)
   .pivot(index='name', columns='col')
   .sort_index(level='col', axis=1, sort_remaining=False)
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}'
                                            if x[0] == 'class' else x[0]),
                              axis=1))
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
    name  class1  #absence  class2  #absence  class3  #absence
0  name1  class1         1  class2         5  class3         3
1  name2  class1         6  class2         4  class3         7
```

Comment: Wow....this is very elegant and works perfectly.  It will take me an hour or so to unpack everything that you did here, but thank you...this is exactly what I was looking for : )